# Scoped proxy isn't created for @Bean-defined beans (Spring 4.0.5)

Tags: spring

I have the following config:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="my.spring.mvc" scoped-proxy="targetClass"/>
```

I was expected that all my scoped beans would be wrapped, but it doesn't affect those that were created in my `@Configuration` class via `@Bean`. To be more concrete:

```
@Component
@Scope("request")
public class Bean1 {}
```

works fine, but:

```
// <- no annotations here
public class Bean1
```

+

```
@Configuration
public class BeansProducer {
    @Bean
    @Scope(value="request")
    public Bean1 bean1() {
        return new Bean1();
    }
}
```

doesn't inject scoped bean (I get `Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean`)

**Is it possible to make @Bean-beans to be scoped in accordance with the `component-scan`'s setting as it happens in case of regular `@Component`s?**

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware - it is not possible. I see two options:

1. Annotate add `proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS` to your `@Scope` annotation.

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public Bean1 bean1() {
    return new Bean1();
}
```

2. If you don't want to repeat all the time `@Scope` annotation with all the details you can create your custom annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
@interface RequestScoped {

}
```

And annotate your bean like:

```
@Bean
@RequestScoped
public Bean1 bean1() {
    return new Bean1();
}
```